# Modelling domain classes in scala

Tags: scala

Our application requires a domain model with perhaps seventy or more fields.
Many of the fields can logically be grouped together.

My initial idea is to use several case classes, and **composition**.
For illustration:

```
case class UserEvents(e1:String, e2:String, e3:String, e4:String...)
case class UserPreferences(p1:String, p2:String, p3;String, p4:String ...)
case class UserHistory(hi:String, h2:String, h3:String, h4:String ...)
case class User(id:Int, name:String, ue:UserEvents, up:UserPreferences, uh:UserHistory)
```

Is this good design?

An alternative would be to model `UserEvents`, `UserPreferences` and `UserHistory` as **traits**, and have `User` extend those. Which approach would be better?

Also: I understand that in Scala, being a functional language, it is considered good practice to keep domain classes lean, and place the logic that acts upon the domain classes in separate objects (the *anemic domain model*). Is this correct?

Thanks

Comment: You are talking about pattern that *aggregate* objects together. I would recommend reading http://debasishg.blogspot.com/2014/04/functional-patterns-in-domain-modeling.html

Comment: I think in functional languages, the idea is modules are the units of 'cohesion' rather than classes. So yes, you might have data structures and functions that act on them. I'm not sure how this applies to Scala, but it does apply to most of the LISP derivatives such as Clojure, as you need generic accessors/setters to be able to deal with this and not become a maintenance nightmare..

Answer (score 3):

Generally, Scala lacks opinions on best practices, and allows for many possible paradigms. It's a very flexible (*Scal*able) language.

> An alternative would be to model UserEvents, UserPreferences and UserHistory as traits, and have User extend those. Which approach would be better?

In an OO-paradigm, you'd ask the question of whether the relationship was a *has-a* relationship (composition), or a *is-a* relationship (inheritance). But's that just OO-design.

The other question that could be asked is whether the relationship will be any different than 1:1. If so, you must use composition.

I typically prefer composition because I find it easier to understand, and there no diamond dependency problem, e.g. with generics.

> Also: I understand that in Scala, being a functional language, it is considered good practice to keep domain classes lean, and place the logic that acts upon the domain classes in separate objects (the anemic domain model). Is this correct?

Again, it depends.

Scala makes it much easier to define data types than, say, Java. So a lot of people use this capability.

I prefer the anemic domain model, as I find separating data and logic helpful. But again, you won't get a canonical answer to this question.